# How to view multiple files in single terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, tail

Sometimes I may need to access multiple log files for troubleshooting , but I don't want to open them in different terminals.

What I want is to open them in same terminal.

Is there any way I can view tail part of the multiple log files in a same terminal window ?

Comment: I don't have the time to post it as an answer, but you can open many files in one vim window.

Comment: ...well, there's always `tmux`...

Answer (score 22):

If you have for example `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/auth.log` log files, you can view them both in one terminal by executing `tail -f` command .

**Open terminal and add the following command**:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog  /var/log/auth.log
```

**The output:**

```
==> /var/log/syslog <==
Mar  4 17:44:15 client AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting due to inactivity
    Mar  4 17:44:15 client dbus[815]: [system] Activating service name='org.debian.apt' (using servicehelper)


==> /var/log/auth.log <==
Mar  4 16:17:01 client CRON[13628]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  4 16:17:01 client CRON[13628]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Answer (score 9):

To view tail part of multiple files in the single terminal window you can install [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) :

```
sudo apt-get install multitail
```

Usage: `multitail <filename1> <filename2>`.

So the output will be  part of file1 and part of file2 in the same terminal.

hope that helps.

Comment: I've found this to be by far the most convenient way to monitor multiple log files. Very handy to work with and is customizable beyond belief. It can even stream log files to a specified port to be tail-ed from a remote machine. Can't recommend it enough.

Answer (score 5):

If you have to `ssh` into a remote machine to watch the logs there, you can run `tmux` (or `screen`) there , and tail the logs in split windows. Works local as well.

Answer (score 4):

In the default `gnome-terminal`, you can just use tabs - ***'File'*** -> ***'New Tab'***

[image]

You can switch between the tabs with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB NUMBER</kbd> , each tab behaves similar to a new terminal. You can also switch with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDwn</kbd> .

You can also detach one of the tabs into a new terminal window with ***'Terminal'*** -> ***'Detach Tab'*** .

Comment: you really didnt get my point. I dont want to do it in many terminals.I want to do it in single terminal.

Comment: Sorry... just thought I would add in a conventional way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tabnew <filename>` in **vim**. To switch between tabs you can use `Ctrl`+`PgUp` and `Ctrl`+`PgDwn`.

You can jump to the end of file by pressing <kbd>G</kbd> in Terminal.